# Can someone explain PriorityQueue in this example to me?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I am trying to learn how to use a PriorityQueue, as I have never used one before. Here is an example of one in use that I have found on LeetCode for a problem that finds the Top K elements in an array of strings

```
public List<String> topKFrequent(String[] words, int k) {
    Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap();
    for (String word: words) {
        count.put(word, count.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
    }
    PriorityQueue<String> heap = new PriorityQueue<String>(
            (w1, w2) -> count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ?
            w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w1) - count.get(w2) );

    for (String word: count.keySet()) {
        heap.offer(word);
        if (heap.size() > k) heap.poll();
    }

    List<String> ans = new ArrayList();
    while (!heap.isEmpty()) ans.add(heap.poll());
    Collections.reverse(ans);
    return ans;
}
```

More notably I would like to know what this line is doing:

```
PriorityQueue<String> heap = new PriorityQueue<String>(
            (w1, w2) -> count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ?
            w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w1) - count.get(w2) );
```

Can someone explain in lame-man's terms what is happening here? Is there any way to rewrite the comparater as a regular "if" statement?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "If counts are equal then compare alphabetically, otherwise compare by counts".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression you have in the constructor is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Because [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a functional interface, that is, it's an interface with only one abstract method, a lambda expression can be used as shorthand for creating an anonymous class.

In your example,

```
new PriorityQueue<String>((w1, w2) -> count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ? w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w1) - count.get(w2));
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
new PriorityQueue<String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String w1, String w2) {
        return count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ? w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w1) - count.get(w2);
    }
});
```

This would also be the same as making a separate class that implements `Comparator<String>`, and passing an instance of that class as the parameter to the `PriorityQueue`.

As for writing the `Comparator` as an if statement, the short answer is, no. The comparator has to be an instance of `Comparator<String>`. However, perhaps a more understandable version of the same comparator is as follows:

```
new PriorityQueue<String>((w1, w2) -> {
    if (count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2))) { // If the counts of w1 and w2 are the same,
        return w2.compareTo(w1); // Then return the reverse lexicographical ordering of w1 and w2 (e.g. "Zebra" comes before "Apple")
    } else if (count.get(w1) < count.get(w2)) {
        return -1; // w1 comes before w2
    } else {
        return 1; // w1 comes after w2
    }
});
```

*Note: "Lexicographical ordering" is essentially alphabetical ordering, but based on ASCII codes. For more information, see [`String#compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))*

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't begin to tell you how thankful I am for you writing this out. This is the best explanation I have found after hours of searching online. Thank you so much.

Comment: Absolutely, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

The `PriorityQueue` constructor you're using is declared as:

```
public PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

It takes a comparator of object of the generic type argument. The `comparator` constructor parameter is described as:

> the comparator that will be used to order this priority queue. If null, the natural ordering of the elements will be used.

In your call, the argument is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) that provides implements `Comparator<String>`. It's roughly equivalent to the following anonymous class:

```
PriorityQueue<String> heap2 = new PriorityQueue<String>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String w1, String w2) {

        if(count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2))) {
            return w2.compareTo(w1);
        } else {
            return count.get(w1) - count.get(w2);
        }

        // can also just be (without the if/else above):
        //return count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ? w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w1) - count.get(w2);
    }
});
```